# Very poor dice coefficient in MIT road and building dataset using UNET

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, image-segmentation

```
def Network(self):

    inputs = Input(shape=(512, 512, 1), batch_shape=None)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(
        UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(drop5))
    merge6 = merge([drop4, up6], mode='concat', concat_axis=3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(
        UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6))
    merge7 = merge([conv3, up7], mode='concat', concat_axis=3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(
        UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7))
    merge8 = merge([conv2, up8], mode='concat', concat_axis=3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(
        UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8))
    merge9 = merge([conv1, up9], mode='concat', concat_axis=3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)
    model = Model(input=inputs, output=conv10)

    return model
```

The dataset consists of 137 building images and label. After 10 epochs dice coeff (accuracy) is not increasing from 0.2.

I am using learning rate of 0.0001 and Adam optimiser. 
I am a learner ,what should i do to increase my dice coefficient?
Do i need a different model or more dataset?

Comment: if you only have 137 images in your dataset that's too low for training a neural network. Increase the dataset and use heavy augmentation.

Comment: Are you augmenting your training data at all? As @thefifthjack005 suggests, 137 is not a good enough sample size to Train image segmentation on. Are you also using a validation set?